# Returning An Xml String To Client Code From C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, xml

I am reading a file from the user files that contains xml that I am processing in a Generic Handler and then passing to the client.

The problem I am having is when I pass the string of xml to the client. Its not in the proper format. It removes the root tag and  `"<xml 1.0>"` tag entirely when looking at it through the client code.

I am looking for some code to preserve the xml string as is when it gets to the client.

I am reading the xml out of a file using `System.IO` on the server..

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {
        string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/Temp");
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

        var file = context.Request.Files[0];

        string fileName;

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE")
        {
            string[] files = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
            fileName = files[files.Length - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = file.FileName;
        }

        string strFileName = fileName;
        fileName = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        file.SaveAs(fileName);
        string msg = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        File.Delete(fileName);

        context.Response.Write(msg);
    }
}
```

The xml always starts at "Gambardella..." For some reason it cannot read the beginning of the file when being send to the cient.

Here is an image of the sample xml..

[image]

The data is sent out of the handler fine but the client cuts off the top information. It looks like the plugin I am using is storing the (or getting) the data from an iframe. Could the iframe maybe be the culprit in cutting off the beginning xml??

The sample client code I am using is [here](http://www.phpletter.com/Our-Projects/AjaxFileUpload/)

Comment: Are you sending the filedata xml as a string to the user?

Comment: "The xml always starts at "Gambardella..." For some reason it cannot read the beginning of the file when being send to the cient.". I suspect you are using a _web browser_ to view this. View the source - you are probably sending the file as `text/html` instead as `application/xml`, meaning the browser will attempt to show it as html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`Response.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.web.httpresponse.writefile.aspx), instead of reading the file then sending it.

```
Response.WriteFile(fileName);
```

This will return the contents of the file with the correct HTTP `Content-Type` header. If the file has the XML declaration, it will not remove it.

---

Something like the following, based on your code and untested (an without a `MemoryStream`, as it is not needed in this case):

```
var file = context.Request.Files[0];
file.InputStream.CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream)
```

Comment: The issue is I have to delete the file after I read. In order to read the file I have to save it to a directory on the server, then read it, then delete it. I cannot save Response.WriteFile it returns void

Comment: @NickLaMarca - Why write it to disk at all? You can do everything with streams (and `MemoryStream` in particular).

Comment: I am writing to a disk to be able to read the xml out of the file. Is there a better way? all I want to accomplish is get the xml out of the file and send the xml as is back to the client

Comment: @NickLaMarca - As I said, if you are creating a string, you can simply create a `MemoryStream` from it, never writing to disk, and using `Response.OutputStream` to output it. Like I asked - why are you writing to disk in the first place?

Comment: Can you show me an example of this? I am having the user call a Generic Handler sending a file from their local disk. Then in order to read it I have to save it to disk on the server. I am not familiar with the alerternate approach you are suggesting.

Comment: Through the HttpContext object. I updated myhandler code above

Comment: @Nick - Posed example. No need to save, no need for a `MemoryStream` either. You may need to tweak it so you send the correct headers though.

Comment: I am having difficulty seeing how I am going to return Response.OutputStream to the client. Currently I am successfully returning the text with context.Response.Wrtie(msg)

Comment: @Nick - So? Instead of `context.Response.Write(msg)`, you do `context.Response.OutputStream.Write(file.InputStream);`

Comment: Yea thats what I tried but that wont compile it says there is no overload for it

Comment: Write wants a buffer[], int offset, int count

Comment: @Nick - Yeah, untested code and all... Wrote it from memory. There is a good example on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx

Comment: This code has the same issue as saving and reading. It wont preserve the xml

Comment: @Nick - I suggest you check the source file then. The code doesn't do _anything_ to the file. If the file does not contain the XML declaration, it will not exist.